python discord bot nextcord slash command Changing the Language
I want to change the name of the slash command differently depending on the discord language of the user.
If the language is Korean:
/서버
If the language is English:
/server
Like this.
I can change the contents inside using ctx.locale, but I also want to change the name and description.
What should I do?
When I asked ChatGPT, they said weird things, and there was no information on Google.
But there is a bot that changes the name of the slash_command depending on the language.
For your information, I am writing the nextcode library.
I really want to do it.
Detailed information was successfully changed from language to language, but name and description failed.

You should use name_localizations and description_localizations. Example:
@nextcord.slash_command(
    name_localizations={
        nextcord.Locale.en_US: "server",
        nextcord.Locale.ko: "서버"
    },
    description_localizations={
        nextcord.Locale.en_US: "Description",
        nextcord.Locale.ko: "설명"
    }
)
async def server(interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
    pass

